# Extracting Frames from an HTMLVideoElement

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, html5-video

So here's my JavaScript code:

```
// Convert Frame to Image
Object.defineProperty(HTMLVideoElement.prototype, 'convertFrameToImage', {
    value: function convertFrameToImage() {
        // Create the Image.
        let image = new Image();

        // Create a Canvas to draw the chosen frame.
        let canvas= document.createElement('canvas'),
            canvasContext = metadata.getContext('2d');

        // Draw the frame.
        canvasContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.offset.height, this.offset.width);

        // Modify the Source of the Image to the Canvas's Data URL.
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL();

        // Return the Image.
        return image
    }
})
```

and with this i was hoping I could create an `Image` out of a specified frame from an `HTMLVideoElement` by setting the `src` of that element to the chosen frame's screen.

I know the code above looks incomplete, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Component is possible with Chrome bur Firefox needs a flag in order to do custom elements

Comment: Yes it's possible. What's your question?

Comment: Thanks. The question is how?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realised the answer to the question was there. Sorry for bothering anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define a `HTMFooBarElement` class the extends `HTMLElement`:

```
class HTMLFooBarElement extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback () {
        this.innerHTML = "Foo-Bar"
    }
}
```

Then extend the `HTMLFooBarELement` class:

```
class FoobBar extends HTMLFooBarElement

customElements.define( "foo-bar", FooBar )
```

```js
class HTMLFooBarElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = "FooBar Element"
  }
};

class FooBar extends HTMLFooBarElement {};

customElements.define("foo-bar", FooBar);
```

```html
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realised though I had already answered my own question.
I'll still look into your answer though.